# How do I access the integers given by nunique in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access the items in each column that is outputted given the following code. It outputs two columns, 'Accurate_Episode_Date' values, and the count (the frequency of each Date). My goal is to plot the date on the x axis, and the count on the y axis using a scatterplot, but first I need to be able to access the actual count values.

```
data = pd.read_csv('CovidDataset.csv')
Barrie = data.loc[data['Reporting_PHU_City'] == 'Barrie']
dates_barrie = Barrie[['Accurate_Episode_Date']]
num = data.groupby('Accurate_Episode_Date')['_id'].nunique()
print(num.tail(5))
```

The code above outputs the following:

```
2021-01-10T00:00:00    1326
2021-01-11T00:00:00    1875
2021-01-12T00:00:00    1274
2021-01-13T00:00:00     492
2021-01-14T00:00:00       8
```

Again, I want to plot the dates on the x axis, and the counts on the y axis in scatterplot form. How do I access the count and date values?

EDIT: I just want a way to plot dates like 2021-01-10T00:00:00 and so on on the x axis, and the corresponding count: 1326 on the Y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was mainly a data type issue. Basically all that was needed was accessing the datetime index and typecasting it to string with `num.index.astype(str)`.

You could probably change it "in-place" and use the plot like below.

```
num.index = num.index.astype(str)
num.plot()
```

---

If you only want to access the values of a DataFrame or Series you just need to access them like this: `num.values`

If you want to plot the date column on X, you don't need to access that column separately, just use pandas internals:

```
# some dummy dates + counts
dates = [datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(1, 6)]
values = np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": dates,
    "Values": values,
})

# if you only have 1 other column you can skip `y`
df.plot(x="Date", y="Values")
```

[image]

Comment: With my specific dataset, how would this work? I'm creating a new DataFrame, and for values I have num.values. How would I access the dates within num? num.values works to get the counts, now how would I get an array of the dates?

Comment: Warnings don't really matter. You can silence them (e.g. `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`) or completely ingore them, or you can just cast the columns to the type you want (e.g. `num["Accurate_Episode_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(num["Accurate_Episode_Date"])` and `num["Count"] = num["Count"].astype(int)`)

Comment: Without converting the datatypes, printing num.values gives me exactly what I want. An array of the counts per day. eg [1 2 5]. I need this for the dates in yyyy-mm-dd format. For some reason, doing ```num["Accurate_Episode_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(num["Accurate_Episode_Date"])``` stops num.values from working. How would I get an array of dates in yyyy-mm-dd format that correspond to those counts?

Comment: I am missing something. You said you want to plot dates on the X axis, and counts on Y, which is what `df.plot` does if you specify them. Just change `df` to `num` and the column names. Why do you need `num.values`??

Comment: I do want to plot, but using ```num.plot(x = "Accurate_Episode_Date", y = "")```, I am not sure of what I should put in the quotations because there is no name to that column. doing  ```num.plot(x = "Accurate_Episode_Date", y = "Count")``` yields an error.  This is because the name of that column with the frequency of each date does not have a name, so I'm not sure what to put in these quotes.

Comment: Oh, then it's probably a series and `num.plot()` may be all you need. Did you try that?

Comment: If not then (and since I haven't used pandas in a while and can't think of stuff) you can always fall back to getting values: `values = num.values` and `dates = num.index` and plotting those with something like `plt.plot(dates, values)`

Comment: It is giving me an error. ```sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (4) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.```

It also gives me an error when I do: ```num["Accurate_Episode_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(num["Accurate_Episode_Date"])``` and ```num["Count"] = num["Count"].astype(int)``` before num.plot()

Comment: The first one is just a warning, not an error. What error does the second give you?

Comment: The second error gives me ```KeyError: 'Count' ```.

So, if I am getting this warning but I still want to plot, how would I do that. I like the idea of ```dates = num.index``` and ```values = num.values``` and to plot that, but with this error, nothing is showing up. I tried ```warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")``` but I'm getting the same warning.

Comment: Oh, then instead of `num["Count"]` you need `num.values.astype(int)`.

Comment: And maybe `num.index.astype(str)` or something

Comment: ```values = num.values.astype(int)
num["Accurate_Episode_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(num["Accurate_Episode_Date"])

num.plot(num["Accurate_Episode_Date"], values)```

gives me ```KeyError: 'Accurate_Episode_Data'```. I've tried so many things I feel like I am getting confused. I appreicate your help

Comment: Can you share a few rows from the csv so I can run the code myself?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for yourhelp! num.index.astypes(str) fixed everything. It worked! Thank you so much :D

Comment: Okay, updated the answer and hopefully it now reflects the solution :D

Comment: @stochasticlover1 remember to accept the answer if it's what you wanted, or suggest edits if it needs improvement.

Comment: Sure, I accepted and upvoted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert date column using `pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])` then you can `plot`

updated answer:

here no need to convert to `pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])`

```
ax=df[['count']].plot()
ax.set_xticks(df.count.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.date)
```

Comment: How about to access the count values?

Comment: what count you want ? can you post what output you want in question?

Comment: I edited the question at the bottom. Please take a look